# Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Signer'. The "$_.HasPrivateKey -eq $true"

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-install-framework

Following this article https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/01/11/playing-with-sitecore-9-0-update-1-installation/comment-page-1/#comment-548 to install Sitecore, got this error on step 13, any idea?

> [---------------------------------------- CreateSignedCert :
>   NewSignedCertificate ------------------------------------] VERBOSE:
>   Resolving ConfigFunction extension 'GetCertificate' VERBOSE: Resolved
>   'Invoke-GetCertificateConfigFunction' VERBOSE:
>   Invoke-GetCertificateConfigFunction VERBOSE: Id:
>   DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert VERBOSE: CertStorePath:
>   cert:\LocalMachine\Root VERBOSE: Found Cert(s) with thumbprint:
>   C6641D4F4CEB3790FCFC82928ED5C2B74B68EDEB Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>   : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Signer'. The
>   "$_.HasPrivateKey -eq $true" validation script for the argument with
>   value "[Subject]   CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert, O=DO_NOT_TRUST,
>   OU=Created by https://www.sitecore.com [Issuer]
>   CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by
>   https://www.sitecore.com [Serial Number]
>   575C8CA6DFB4129D49F47FA7681558D4 [Not Before]   11/28/2018 5:32:24 AM
>   [Not After]   11/26/2028 5:32:24 AM [Thumbprint]
>   C6641D4F4CEB3790FCFC82928ED5C2B74B68EDEB " did not return a result of
>   True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the
>   command again. At C:\Sitecore9\Sitecore 9.0.2 Single
>   Instance\Sitecore902Install.ps1:18 char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
>
> [TIME] 00:00:02 Invoke-NewSignedCertificateTask : Cannot validate
>   argument on parameter 'Signer'. The "$_.HasPrivateKey -eq $true"
>   validation script for the argument with value "[Subject]
>   CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by
>   https://www.sitecore.com [Issuer]   CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert,
>   O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by https://www.sitecore.com [Serial Number]
>   575C8CA6DFB4129D49F47FA7681558D4 [Not Before]   11/28/2018 5:32:24 AM
>   [Not After]   11/26/2028 5:32:24 AM [Thumbprint]
>   C6641D4F4CEB3790FCFC82928ED5C2B74B68EDEB " did not return a result of
>   True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the
>   command again. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641
>   char:47
>   +                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default

[image: Error]

Comment: Where having same issue with the certificate, where you able to manage this?

Comment: If one of the proposed answers fixed your issue, could you please accept that answer?

Answer (score 23):

Below solution worked for me.

Close all active PowerShell sessions, delete all DO_NOT_TRUST* certificates from all certificate store and C:\certificates. Open “**xconnect-createcert.json**” and change json as below.

```
"StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
```

https://mohitdharmadhikari.com/2018/12/25/cannot-validate-argument-on-parameter-signer-sitecore-9-installation/

Answer (score 5):

Encountered the same exact error today. It looks like a new version of the SitecoreInstallFramework was published November 28th (version 2.0.0). It seems to break the process in some way. I solved this by uninstalling the framework and reinstalling with version 1.2.1.

Comment: In my case installing SIF 1.2.1 did not work as well, because the certificates generated are already expired (2018-11-29)

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was using Sitecore Installation Framework version 2.1.0 to install Sitecore version 9.0.1, which does not work.
I ran the following to switch the SIF version:

```
Remove-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.1.0
```

And then deleted the created certificates from previous attempts as per Mohit's answer.

You can determine which versions of SIF you have with this:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -AllVersions
```

Hope his helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you tried to install sitecore 9 in the past.
Changing "RootCertFileName" default value in xconnet-createcert.json to, for example, SIF121Root, fixes the issue.

This link helped me out https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/699694